# How to move marker like car goes on road on a map?

Tags: android

I want move marker(like car goes on road) smoothly on google map in android my application like jugnoo.

Comment: what you tried or searched for this so far ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out how to receive location updates [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)
and then update the position of your marker inside `onLocationChanged`